# How can I get geom_errorbar to "dodge" correctly on a bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a grouped bar chart with error bars.  However, I can't get the error bars to both look correct (i.e., be thinner than the main bars) and positioned correctly (in the center of the bars).  The `position` option and `position_dodge()` don't seem to be working correctly, and I can't figure out why--based on examples in other similar questions, this ought to work.

I'm running ggplot2 version 3.0.0 in R version 3.4.2.

A minimal working example:

```
d<-data.frame(bin = factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3)),type = factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)), beta = c(10,20,30,40,50,60), se = c(2,2,2,2,2,2))
ggplot(d, aes(x=bin,y=beta,ymin = beta - 1.96* se, ymax = beta+1.96* se)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = type), position = position_dodge2(), stat="identity")  +
    geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge2(.9))
```

Produces:[image: Right Position, Too Wide]
Right position, but too wide.  Using `position_dodge()` instead of `position_dodge2()` doesn't even get the position right:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=bin,y=beta,ymin = beta - 1.96* se, ymax = beta+1.96* se)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = type), position = position_dodge(), stat="identity")  +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image: Even wider, and wrong position]
Adding the `width` parameter to `geom_errorbar` breaks the version with `position_dodge2()` and doesn't help the one with `position_dodge()`:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=bin,y=beta,ymin = beta - 1.96* se, ymax = beta+1.96* se)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = type), position = position_dodge2(), stat="identity")  +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge2(.9), width= .2)

ggplot(d, aes(x=bin,y=beta,ymin = beta - 1.96* se, ymax = beta+1.96* se)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = type), position = position_dodge(), stat="identity")  +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width = .2)
```

[image: Good width, wrong position]
[image: Good width, wrong position still]

What's going on here?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you move `fill` into the global `aes()` then `position_dodge()` will work as expected. Alternatively you could add the grouping variable via `group` to `geom_errorbar()`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = bin, y = beta, 
              ymin = beta - 1.96*se, ymax = beta+1.96*se, fill = type)) + 
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity")  +
    geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width = .2)
```

The issue with `position_dodge2()` appears to be what is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2251), which can be solved via the `padding` argument.  Notice there is no longer a `width` argument in `geom_errorbar()` with this approach.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = bin, y = beta, 
              ymin = beta - 1.96*se, ymax = beta+1.96*se, fill = type)) + 
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(), stat="identity")  +
    geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(.9, padding = .6))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Ironically, I found the padding option shortly after posting my question; moving the fill seems cleaner.